# How to save ArrayList as XML

Tags: java, xml, database, arraylist

I have arrayList of objects that each include the following elements:

- Jersey Number
- First Name
- Last Name
- Preferred Position
- Goals
- Assists

Code:

```
ArrayList <blackTeam> blackTeam = new ArrayList <blackTeam>();

...

public class blackTeam {

    int goals, assists;
    String jerseyNum, firstName, lastName, prefPosition;
    
    blackTeam (String _jerseyNum, String _firstName, String _lastName, String _prefPosition, int _goals, int _assists) {
        jerseyNum = _jerseyNum;
        firstName = _firstName;
        lastName = _lastName;
        prefPosition = _prefPosition;
        goals = _goals;
        assists = _assists;
    }
}
```

This is my code for saving the data as XML:

```
        try {
                String filepath = "blackTeam.xml";
                 DocumentBuilderFactory docFactory = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
                 DocumentBuilder docBuilder = docFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
                 Document doc = docBuilder.parse(filepath);

                Element root = doc.createElement("BlackTeam");
                doc.appendChild(root);

                for (int i = 0; i < blackTeam.size(); i++) {
                    Element player = doc.createElement("Player");
                    root.appendChild(player);

                    Element jerseyNum = doc.createElement("JerseyNum");
                    jerseyNum.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(blackTeam.get(i).jerseyNum));
                    player.appendChild(jerseyNum);

                    Element firstName = doc.createElement("FirstName");
                    firstName.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(blackTeam.get(i).firstName));
                    player.appendChild(firstName);

                    Element lastName = doc.createElement("LastName");
                    lastName.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(blackTeam.get(i).lastName));
                    player.appendChild(lastName);

                    Element prefPosition = doc.createElement("PreferredPosition");
                    prefPosition.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(blackTeam.get(i).lastName));
                    player.appendChild(prefPosition);

                    Element goals = doc.createElement("Goals");
                    goals.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(String.valueOf(blackTeam.get(i).goals)));
                    player.appendChild(goals);

                    Element assists = doc.createElement("Assists");
                    assists.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(String.valueOf(blackTeam.get(i).assists)));
                    player.appendChild(assists);
                }

                //write the content into xml file
                TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
                Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
                DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);
                StreamResult result =  new StreamResult(new File(filepath));
                transformer.transform(source, result);

                System.out.println("Done");

            }catch(ParserConfigurationException pce){
                  pce.printStackTrace();
            }catch(TransformerException tfe){
                  tfe.printStackTrace();
            }catch(IOException ioe){
                  ioe.printStackTrace();
            }catch(SAXException sae){
                  sae.printStackTrace();
            }
```

I want the outputted XML to look like this example:

```
<blackTeam>
    <player>
        <jerseyNumber>56</jerseyNumber>
        <firstName>John</firstName>
        <lastName>Smith</lastName>
        <preferredPosition>Center</preferredPosition>
        <goals>45</goals>
        <assists>13</assists>
    </player>
    <player>
        <jerseyNumber>43</jerseyNumber>
        <firstName>Bill</firstName>
        <lastName>Jones</lastName>
        <preferredPosition>Defense</preferredPosition>
        <goals>12</goals>
        <assists>27</assists>
    </player>
<blackTeam>
```

When I run my code I get:

[Fatal Error] blackTeam.xml:1:1: Premature end of file.
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; systemId: file:///D:/Computer%20Science%2012/League_Database/blackTeam.xml; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 1; Premature end of file.

I quite sure that this line is causing an error:

```
Document doc = docBuilder.parse(filepath);
```

Can someone explain to me why my code is not working and provide a solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can not use the method `docBuilder.parse()` in your case. This method is used when you already have an XML file and want to get a Java representation (`Document`) of that XML.

Since you want to create a new file, you should go with this code:

```
Document doc = docBuilder.newDocument();
```